# Cannot display ScrollViewer with stackpanel

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using a `ListBox` and I'm trying to display the scrollviewer but I need to use a stackpanel 'cause I need to align my item in horizontal mode, see the code:

```
<ListBox VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                         Background="AliceBlue"
                         ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding EventInfo}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Gara" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0, 0, 50, 0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding League}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Data" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0, 0, 50, 0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

How you can see I put the `ScrollViewer` outside the `Stackpanel` to make it work. Unfortunately the scrollviewer appear but seems disabled, and seems not working 'cause I should able to scroll the item inside but I can't. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a `ScrollViewer` inside your `DataTemplate`, as the `ListBox` already has a `ScrollViewer` set.

Also, yo should update your `DataTemplate` to use a `Grid` (it's cleaner then stacking `StackPanels`).

```
    <ListBox VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
             Background="AliceBlue"
             ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
             ItemsSource="{Binding EventInfo}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="Gara" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0, 0, 50, 0"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Grid.Row="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding League}" 
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Grid.Row="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Data" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0, 0, 50, 0"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Grid.Row="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Edit: ScrollBar is now visible and works. http://imgur.com/a/t2WPa

Comment: unfortunately the scrollviewer is still disabled

Comment: It's going to be disabled until you have enough data to scroll. how much data is in the ListBox?

Comment: I put 10 items, so it should appear

Comment: Works for me. I'll post a screenshot.

Comment: Also, change ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto". This will only show the ScrollViewer when the content can scroll

Comment: exactly, read my comment - "this will only show the ScrollViewer when the content can scroll". if you cannot see the scroll bar, there's nothing to scroll.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122535/discussion-between-againme-and-d-moncada).

Comment: I fix this myself: CanContentScroll to false, not sure why but working